# Manifest v3 Chrome Extension Screen Recording with Background Script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create an extension to record screen. In manifest version 2 I was using a persistent background script and calling the start function with `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()` and everything was working perfectly. Now I am trying to migrate to v3 and having problems. Basically what I want to do is start screen record with `chrome.desktopCapture` in my background script for the active tab.

When I try to run chrome.desktopCapture in background.js chrome shut itself immediately. Since I cannot use getBackgroundPage anymore, I am passing message between the popup and background.

**The Code:**

```
// popup.html
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    message: "start", 
    tabId: <active-tab-id-here>
    }, (response) => {
           console.log(response.answer);
});
```

```
// background.js

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( (request, _, sendResponse) => {
    switch(request.message) {
        case 'start':
               chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia(['tab', 'screen'], onAccessApproved);
    }
    
    sendResponse({answer: "Message Received Successfully!"});
}
);
```

Comment: There's a bug https://crbug.com/1271590, fixed in Chrome 102, currently Chrome Canary.

Comment: Was facing the same issue :S, thx for putting it on stackoverflow